# Node.js convert Chinese character to \uXXXX

Tags: node.js, encode

I want to convert the string like '字符串' to '\u5B57\u7B26\u4E32', how do I implement in Node.js?

```
function convert(str) {
    //...
}

var s = '字符串'
convert(s); // => \u5B57\u7B26\u4E32
```

Comment: Can you provide the portion of your code where you want to do this conversion?

Comment: I just want to convert the string to \uXXXX encode, do you know some module from npm can do this or how to implement it in my convert function？

Comment: [Here is a blog](http://buildingonmud.blogspot.sg/2009/06/convert-string-to-unicode-in-javascript.html) containing a custom JavaScript function which might work for your case.

Comment: I guess you could try https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can probably be done in a better way (and the already mentioned [`jsesc`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc) is probably a safer choice):

```
function convert(s) {
  return s.split('').map(function(c) {
    return '\\u' + ('0000' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-4);
  }).join('');
}

var s = '字符串';
convert(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
var convert=function(str){
    var codeStr="";
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
      var _code=str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
      codeStr+='\\u'+"0000".substr(0,4-_code.length)+_code
    }
    return codeStr;
}

var s = '字符串'
convert(s);
```